# Further usage of proc sql into (print varname) SAS

Tags: sas

I used the sashelp library data sets as an example

```
proc datasets library=sashelp;
    contents
        data=company
        out=work.var_names;
quit;
run;
```

Now i using proc sql into to store the variable names

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name into: varname separated by ' '
    from var_names;
quit;
%put &varname;
```

Now i would like to print the variables name on the log

```
data newdata (drop=i);
    array temp{*} &varname;
    do i=1 to dim(temp);
        put temp{i};
    end;
run;
```

While it print . instead of the variable names.

Thanks

log:

```
337  %put &varname;
DEPTHEAD JOB1 LEVEL1 LEVEL2 LEVEL3 LEVEL4 LEVEL5 N
```

While i want

```
DEPTHEAD 
JOB1 
LEVEL1 
LEVEL2 
LEVEL3 
LEVEL4 
LEVEL5 
N
```

Comment: Aren't you already printing the variable - "name" into the log, using %put &varname;? Do you want to do the same using datastep?

Comment: @NEOmen please see the amendment. It would be great if i able to only print second element of varname. JOB1

Comment: You can do what you ask, but its not generalizable very much. Perhaps, post what you're trying to do overall instead. Also, look at sashelp.vcolumn as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the premise of this question, as you're doing something waaaaay more complicated than you need to.

First of all, you don't need proc contents.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name into :varname separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='SASHELP' and memname='COMPANY';
quit;
```

Second, this is a much easier way to get the variable names, even assuming you don't want them as %put.

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.company;
  array _names &varname.;
  do _i = 1 to dim(_names);
    _v = vname(_names[_i]);
    put _v=;
  end;
run;
```

I don't see what value a `_temporary_` array has here at all.  `vname` will happily give you the names of the variables in the array, if that's what you're after.  Honestly this seems like a contrived example though as Reese and others pointed out.

Comment: Hi Joe, maybe i still have the mindset of R programming. As i am having the early stage to study SAS. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @useR The main thing to understand about SAS that's different from R, is that datasets are the main item you work with, not vectors.  It's not dissimilar from the change from `c` to `c++`, where you change from using functions to using objects (not the same change, but the same variety of change).  SAS is very efficient when your data is organized properly in a dataset; it is a lot of work if you're trying to use macro lists and macro loops and such to replicate R.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the variables in the company are name, salary, the varname macro variable is "name salary". When the last segments were run, it is acually like this:

`array temp{*} name salary;`

The name and salary are set to default numeric variables with missing value '.'.

Why not just put the variables in the var_names:

```
data _null_;
    set var_names;
    put name;
run;
```

Comment: what if i just want to get the 2nd item of the array varname? 
like name{2} ?

Comment: @useR `varname` is not an array, it's a macro variable containing a list of names.  This isn't R.  I have a feeling this is confusion originating from that - I highly recommend abandoning the idea of using macro variables as if they were R vectors.  They're not, and shouldn't be used as such in most cases.  SAS is very powerful, but *not* like R in this fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why your method is not working, but for now you can use `scan` function to extract the elements, code is pretty much self explanatory, let me know if you don't get it

```
data _null_;
array temp{*} &varname;
do i=1 to dim(temp);
temp_1 = scan("&varname.",i);
put temp_1;
end;
second_element=scan("&varname.",2);
put second_element=;
run;
```

**EDIT:**
Your method

```
array temp{*} &varname
```

which eventually translates to

```
array temp{*} DEPTHEAD JOB1 LEVEL1 LEVEL2 LEVEL3 LEVEL4 LEVEL5 N;
```

is not working because by doing that **array variable names are defined and not the values are initialized**

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201956.htm

Look for this statement

```
array simple{3} red green yellow;
```

If you want to do it your way then you have to do something like this

```
data _null_;
   array tempar{8} $ tempar1-tempar8 ("DEPTHEAD" "JOB1" "LEVEL1" "LEVEL2" "LEVEL3" "LEVEL4" "LEVEL5" "N");
   do i=1 to dim(tempar);
   put tempar(i)=;
   end;
run;
```

Notice first I have defined the individual elements of the array - `tempar1-tempar8` and have defined it `char` using `$` and then I have intialized the values that too in quotes.

---

**EDIT2:**

**Tested**
If you absolutely can't deviate from your approach, below is the code(which is less efficient than what I have suggested above)

```
   proc datasets library=sashelp;
    contents
        data=company
        out=work.var_names;
quit;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select quote(compress(name)) into: varname separated by ' '
    from var_names;
    select count(name) into: Numofelements from var_names;
quit;

%put %quote(&varname.);
%put &Numofelements;

data _null_;
   array tempar{%sysfunc(compress(&Numofelements.))} $ tempar1-tempar%sysfunc(compress(&Numofelements.)) (%quote(&varname.));
   do i=1 to dim(tempar);
   put tempar(i)=;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. While is it possible to generalize the case that i do not know how many variables i have in the data sets? it is not given the number 8.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a long way to do something that may be accomplished more easily, if you explained why you wanted to do it :). 
Here's a solution that uses a stores the values using quotes and then puts them into a temporary array.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select quote(trim(name)) into: varname separated by ' '
    from var_names;
quit;
%put &varname;

data new data;
array var_names{&sqlobs} $ _temporary_  (&varname);
put var_names(2);
do i=1 to dim(var_names);
   put var_names(i);
end;
run;
```

Here's a second solution that uses your dataset, since I find it a good practice to avoid macros wherever possible.

```
data newdata;
   set var_names;
   if _n_=2 then put name;
run;
```

And a note that you can use the

```
 _all_, _numeric_ or _character_
```

shortcut to reference variable lists. An array can only have one type, so I assume that all variables are numeric or character. As well as the fact that SASHELP.VCOLUMN contains various metadata about all SAS library and tables.

Comment: your code is not gonna work because, the quotes are missing from the individiual data elements which is necessary for the character data.

Comment: That's why there's a quote function in the proc SQL, or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Yeah that part is right, it is throwing error below that - ERROR: Attempt to initialize variable _temp_ in numeric array var_names with character constant "DEPTHEAD                        ".

Comment: Thanks! SAS wants the full word temporary instead of temp.

Comment: As I executed your code, it is still throwing the error,upon researching , I found that - •You cannot use the special subscript asterisk (*) to refer to all the elements with the _temporary_ arrays.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201956.htm

Comment: I don't mind, but you should use the automatic macro variable sqlobs

Comment: Thanks Reese and NEOmen, as i just learning sas programming and sorry for my confusing no-specific target question. As i stick to the idea of R programming.